# Chrome browser opened by selenium running in daemon thread does not close with main thread python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, customtkinter

I am initiating browser automation using selenium from a `CustomTkinter` GUI. I am running my automation inside daemon thread.

When i click on stop button in between execution my UI terminates as expected. This also stops my selenium automation but my browser is not getting closed.

Below is the structure of my code:

```py
    def start(self):
        daemon_thread = Thread(target=self.main, daemon=True)
        daemon_thread.start()

    def exit_app(self):
        self.destroy()

    def main(self):
        app = MyWebApp()
        app.main()
```

Here i tried to make my `daemon_thread` a class attribute and call `exit` and `join` method on it in the `exit_app` method but that does not terminate the `daemon_thread`  at all and keep running my automation in the background even through the UI is terminated.

Please help.

Comment: Do you want to get the structure of the answer or the answer itself? Please create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call close on your driver before closing your threads/app. Usually you can just call driver.close()